# Getting issue to add herokuconnect addon

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, salesforce

Please have a look.

rails@rails-desktop:~/rails/app$ heroku addons:add herokuconnect
Adding herokuconnect on app... failed
! That add-on plan is only available to select users.

I am unable to add this add-on.

Please describe that what is the issue.

Comment: It looks like the error message is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Go to https://www.heroku.com/connect please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give one try to add this addon from Heroku Addon Dashboard Interface.
This is because Heroku connect is available to selected business users.
And you have to tell business purpose to Heroku for using Heroku connect to get this addon.

Answer (score 3):

Actually looks like **heroku-postgresql** has been updated to **heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev**

```
liango@LENOVO-PC D:\lianxi\shouter
>  heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
Creating postgresql-globular-2767... done, (free)
Adding postgresql-globular-2767 to whispering-meadow-8682... done
Setting DATABASE_URL and restarting whispering-meadow-8682... done, v4
Database has been created and is available
 ! This database is empty. If upgrading, you can transfer
 ! data from another database with pg:copy
Use `heroku addons:docs heroku-postgresql` to view documentation.

liango@LENOVO-PC D:\lianxi\shouter
>
```

Comment: Have been searching for this answer for hours now- works perfectly- thanks for the tip!